# Web host tracking - cannot find my host

Tags: web-hosting

I hope this is the right place to ask such question.

EDIT: And this question is not duplicate! I tried tracking down the host using services such as whois but they didn't provide an answer. So that route is not working

I have a client with a website but they don't remember their hosting provider. Upon searching based on the ip or the domain (using services such as whois) it still cannot be found.

I do have the credentials inlcuding the computer name, and upon searching based on the computer name I am directed to softLayer hosting provider. But they do not agree to provide any information. Could it be that the host actually uses softLayer service? (but again I don't know who the host is...)

The reason why I'm trying to find the hosting provider is that although I have the credentials, when trying to connect with WinSCP, I'm receving 'access denied'.

Is there something else I can do in order to find that hosting provider?

Thanks in advance